# Better way to search for date in table and if not found then insert date

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following code to search column A for the date of a document that I am trying to import and if not found then insert a new row and import the data:

```
' If the document date is earlier than the date in the first line of the spreadsheet search for the date in the A column
ElseIf strSheetDate > strFileNameDate Then
    Set rngSheetDate = WS1.Range("A:A").Find(strFileNameDate)

    ' If the date is found in A column then add the data to that row
    If Not rngSheetDate Is Nothing Then 'when rng <> nothing means found something'

        If WS2.Cells(2, 2).Value <> "" Then WS1.Range(rngSheetDate.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = WS1.Range(rngSheetDate.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value + WS2.Cells(2, 2).Value
        If WS2.Cells(3, 2).Value <> "" Then WS1.Range(rngSheetDate.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value = WS1.Range(rngSheetDate.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value + WS2.Cells(3, 2).Value


    Else

        ' If it is not found then look for dates either side of the document date and then insert a new line for that record
        iRow2 = WS1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngSheetDate2 = WS1.Range("A2:A" & iRow2)
        For Each cell In rngSheetDate2

            If cell.Value > strFileNameDate And cell.Offset(1, 0).Value < strFileNameDate Then

                WS1.Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), cell.Offset(1, 4)).Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = strFileNameDate

                If WS2.Cells(2, 2).Value <> "" Then
                    cell.Offset(1, 1).Value = WS2.Cells(2, 2).Value
                Else
                    cell.Offset(1, 1).Value = 0
                End If

                If WS2.Cells(3, 2).Value <> "" Then
                    cell.Offset(1, 3).Value = WS2.Cells(3, 2).Value
                Else
                    cell.Offset(1, 3).Value = 0
                End If

                Exit For

            End If
        Next

    End If                
End If
```

There must be a better way to search for a string in column 1 of the table and if not found then add a new line in the middle of the table or add to the bottom.

any advice ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a better way" ? What is the problem with your code?

Comment: @LineBreak sorry i'm not good at explaining what i want. The code works ok but would like to see if there is a way of condensing the code so that I can use the same code to process other files (other .csv files that have different data in but need to be added on a single row). It's not my best work as wrote a long time ago but don't know where to start

Comment: To evaluate working code, you should redirect your question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is for the code to be condensed, you can remove a lot of the superfluous .Value etc...

Also the If-ElseIf can be recoded ass they are simple using the IIf function

Normally setting code within 'With' statements also helps shorten code as well as being more efficient - but there isn't really much here that warrants it

For example:

```
' If the document date is earlier than the date in the first line of the spreadsheet search for the date in the A column
ElseIf strSheetDate > strFileNameDate Then
    Set rngSheetDate = WS1.Range("A:A").Find(strFileNameDate)

    ' If the date is found in A column then add the data to that row
    If Not rngSheetDate Is Nothing Then         'when rng <> nothing means found something
        If WS2.Cells(2, 2) <> "" Then rngSheetDate.Offset(0, 1) = rngSheetDate.Offset(0, 1) + WS2.Cells(2, 2)
        If WS2.Cells(3, 2) <> "" Then rngSheetDate.Offset(0, 3) = rngSheetDate.Offset(0, 3) + WS2.Cells(3, 2)
    Else
        ' If it is not found then look for dates either side of the document date and then insert a new line for that record
        iRow2 = WS1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngSheetDate2 = WS1.Range("A2:A" & iRow2)
        For Each Cell In rngSheetDate2
            If Cell > strFileNameDate And Cell.Offset(1, 0) < strFileNameDate Then
                WS1.Range(Cell.Offset(1, 0), Cell.Offset(1, 4)).Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                Cell.Offset(1, 0) = strFileNameDate
                Cell.Offset(1, 1) = IIf(WS2.Cells(2, 2) <> "", WS2.Cells(2, 2), 0)
                Cell.Offset(1, 3) = IIf(WS2.Cells(3, 2) <> "", WS2.Cells(3, 2), 0)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
```

Comment: well that is a lot cleaner than my effort and I never knew about IIF. Thank you